# Reference to value of the function

Tags: python, python-2.7

At beginning i wanna say i'm newbie in use Python and everything I learned it came from tutorials. 
My problem concerning reference to the value. I'm writing some script which is scrapping some information from web sites. I defined some function:

```
def MatchPattern(count):
    sock = urllib.urlopen(Link+str(count))
    htmlSource = sock.read()                             
    sock.close()
    root = etree.HTML(htmlSource)
    root = etree.HTML(htmlSource)
    result = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, method="html")
    expr1 = check_reg(root)
    expr2 = check_practice(root)
    D_expr1 = no_ks(root)
    D_expr2 = Registred_by(root)
    D_expr3 = Name_doctor(root)
    D_expr4 = Registration_no(root) 
    D_expr5 = PWZL(root)
    D_expr6 = NIP(root)
    D_expr7 = Spec(root)
    D_expr8 = Start_date(root)

    #-----Reg_practice-----
    R_expr1 = Name_of_practise(root) 
    R_expr2 = TERYT(root) 
    R_expr3 = Street(root)
    R_expr4 = House_no(root)
    R_expr5 = Flat_no(root)
    R_expr6 = Post_code(root)
    R_expr7 = City(root)
    R_expr8 = Practice_no(root)
    R_expr9 = Kind_of_practice(root)

    #------Serv_practice -----
    S_expr1 = TERYT2(root)
    S_expr2 = Street2(root)
    S_expr3 = House_no2(root)
    S_expr4 = Flat_no2(root)
    S_expr5 = Post_code2(root)
    S_expr6 = City2(root)
    S_expr7 = Phone_no(root)

    return expr1
    return expr2
    return D_expr1
    return D_expr2
    return D_expr3
    return D_expr4 
    return D_expr5
    return D_expr6
    return D_expr7
    return D_expr8

    #-----Reg_practice-----
    return R_expr1 
    return R_expr2
    return R_expr3
    return R_expr4
    return R_expr5
    return R_expr6
    return R_expr7
    return R_expr8
    return R_expr9

    #------Serv_practice -----
    return S_expr1
    return S_expr2
    return S_expr3
    return S_expr4
    return S_expr5
    return S_expr6
    return S_expr7
```

So now inside the script I wanna check value of the expr1 returned by my fynction. I don't know how to do that. Can u guys help me ? Is my function written correct ?

EDIT:
I can't add answer so I edit my current post

This is my all script. Some comments are in my native language but i add some in english

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#encoding:UTF-8-

# ----------------------------- importujemy potrzebne biblioteki i skrypty -----------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import urllib
from lxml import etree, html
import sys
import re
import MySQLdb as mdb
from TOR_connections import *
from XPathSelection import *
import os

# ------------------------------ Definiuje xPathSelectors ------------------------------------------
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -------Doctors -----
check_reg = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[1]/tr[3]/td[2]/text())") #warunek Lekarz
check_practice = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[3]/tr[4]/td[2]/text())") #warunek praktyka

no_ks = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/text())")
Registred_by = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[1]/tr[4]/td[2]/text())")
Name_doctor = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[2]/td[2]/text())")
Registration_no = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[3]/td[2]/text())") 
PWZL = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[4]/td[2]/text())") 
NIP = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[5]/td[2]/text())") 
Spec = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[18]/td[2]/text())") 
Start_date = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[20]/td[2]/text())") 

#-----Reg_practice-----
Name_of_practise = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[1]/td[2]/text())") 
TERYT = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[7]/td[2]/*/text())") 
Street = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[8]/td[2]/text())") 
House_no = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[9]/td[2]/*/text())")
Flat_no = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[10]/td[2]/*/text())")
Post_code = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[11]/td[2]/*/text())")
City = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[12]/td[2]/*/text())") 
Practice_no = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[3]/tr[4]/td[2]/text())")
Kind_of_practice = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[3]/tr[5]/td[2]/text())")

#------Serv_practice -----
TERYT2 = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[3]/tr[14]/td/table/tr[2]/td[2]/*/text())") 
Street2 = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[3]/tr[14]/td/table/tr[3]/td[2]/text())") 
House_no2 = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[3]/tr[14]/td/table/tr[4]/td[2]/*/text())") 
Flat_no2 = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[3]/tr[14]/td/table/tr[5]/td[2]/i/text())") 
Post_code2 = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[3]/tr[14]/td/table/tr[6]/td[2]/*/text())") 
City2 = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[3]/tr[14]/td/table/tr[7]/td[2]/*/text())")
Phone_no = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[3]/tr[14]/td/table/tr[8]/td[2]/text())")

# --------------------------- deklaracje zmiennych globalnych ----------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
decrease = 9
No = 1
Link = "http://rpwdl.csioz.gov.pl/rpz/druk/wyswietlKsiegaServletPub?idKsiega="

# --------------------------- funkcje zdefiniowane ----------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def MatchPattern(count):
    sock = urllib.urlopen(Link+str(count))
    htmlSource = sock.read()                             
    sock.close()
    root = etree.HTML(htmlSource)
    root = etree.HTML(htmlSource)
    result = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, method="html")
    expr1 = check_reg(root)
    expr2 = check_practice(root)
    D_expr1 = no_ks(root)
    D_expr2 = Registred_by(root)
    D_expr3 = Name_doctor(root)
    D_expr4 = Registration_no(root) 
    D_expr5 = PWZL(root)
    D_expr6 = NIP(root)
    D_expr7 = Spec(root)
    D_expr8 = Start_date(root)

    #-----Reg_practice-----
    R_expr1 = Name_of_practise(root) 
    R_expr2 = TERYT(root) 
    R_expr3 = Street(root)
    R_expr4 = House_no(root)
    R_expr5 = Flat_no(root)
    R_expr6 = Post_code(root)
    R_expr7 = City(root)
    R_expr8 = Practice_no(root)
    R_expr9 = Kind_of_practice(root)

    #------Serv_practice -----
    S_expr1 = TERYT2(root)
    S_expr2 = Street2(root)
    S_expr3 = House_no2(root)
    S_expr4 = Flat_no2(root)
    S_expr5 = Post_code2(root)
    S_expr6 = City2(root)
    S_expr7 = Phone_no(root)

    return expr1
    return expr2
    return D_expr1
    return D_expr2
    return D_expr3
    return D_expr4 
    return D_expr5
    return D_expr6
    return D_expr7
    return D_expr8

    #-----Reg_practice-----
    return R_expr1 
    return R_expr2
    return R_expr3
    return R_expr4
    return R_expr5
    return R_expr6
    return R_expr7
    return R_expr8
    return R_expr9

    #------Serv_practice -----
    return S_expr1
    return S_expr2
    return S_expr3
    return S_expr4
    return S_expr5
    return S_expr6
    return S_expr7




# --------------------------- ustanawiamy polaczenie z baza danych -----------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '******', 'SANBROKER', charset='utf8');

# ---------------------------- początek programu -----------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

with con: 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT Old_num FROM SANBROKER.Number_of_records;")
    Old_num = cur.fetchone()
    count = Old_num[0]
    counter = input("Input number of rows: ")

    # ----------------------- pierwsze połączenie z TORem ------------------------------------
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #connectTor()
    #conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("my-ip.heroku.com")
    #conn.request("GET", "/")
    #response = conn.getresponse()
    #print(response.read())

    while count <= counter: # co dziesiata liczba
        # --------------- pierwsze wpisanie do bazy danych do Archive --------------------
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("UPDATE SANBROKER.Number_of_records  SET Archive_num=%s",(count))

        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if decrease == 0:
            MatchPattern(count)

            # Now I wanna check some expresions (2 or 3)
            # After that i wanna write all the values into my database


            #------- ostatnie czynności:
            percentage = count / 100
            print "rekordów: " + str(count) + " z: " + str(counter) + " procent dodanych: " + str(percentage) + "%"  
            with con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute("UPDATE SANBROKER.Number_of_records SET Old_num=%s",(count))
            decrease = 10-1
            count +=1
        else:
            MatchPattern(count)

            # Now I wanna check some expresions (2 or 3)
            # After that i wanna write all the values into my database

            # ------ ostatnie czynności:
            percentage = count / 100
            print "rekordów: " + str(count) + " z: " + str(counter) + " procent dodanych: " + str(percentage) + "%"
            with con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute("UPDATE SANBROKER.Number_of_records SET Old_num=%s",(count))
            decrease -=1
            count +=1
```

Comment: In a function, when `return` is encountered, the functions stops running, and the code placed after is ignored. This means your function will stops at `return expr1`. Check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm assuming check_reg is a function that returns a boolean (either True or False).

If that's the case, to check the return:

```
if expr1:
   print "True."
else: 
   print "False"
```

There's more than one way to do it, but basically, `if expr1:` is all you need to do the checking.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the return value of a function, assign the function to a name with an equal sign, like this:

```
return_value = somefunction(some_value)
print('The return value is ',return_value)
```

Keep in mind that when the first `return` statement is encountered, the function will exit. So if you have more than one return statement after each other, only the first will execute.

If you want to return multiple things, add them to a list and then return the list.

Here is an improved version of your function:

```
def match_pattern(count):

    sock = urllib.urlopen(Link+str(count))
    htmlsource = sock.read()                             
    sock.close()
    root = etree.HTML(htmlSource)
    # root = etree.HTML(htmlSource) - duplicate line
    # result = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, method="html")
    function_names = [check_reg, check_practice, no_ks, Registered_by, \
                      Name_doctor, Registration_no, PWZL, NIP, Spec, Start_date, \
                      Name_of_practise, TERYT, Street, House_no2, Flat_no, \
                      Post_code2, City2, Phone_no]
    results = []
    for function in function_names:
         results.append(function(root))

    return results

r = match_pattern(1)
print r[0] # this will be the result of check_reg(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is quite ambigous. Can you please fix the ident to let us know what belongs to the function and which part is the script.

A function can returns only one value. You cannot do :

```
return something
return something_else
return ...
```

The function will ends when first value will be returned.
What you can do is returning a list, tuple or dict containing all your values.
For instance :

```
return (something,something_else,...)
```

or

```
return [something,something_else,...]
```

In your case, it seems better to create a class that would have all values you want as attributes, and turn this function into a method that would set the attributes values.

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__ ( self , link , count ):

        sock = urllib.urlopen(link+str(count))
        htmlSource = sock.read()                             
        sock.close()
        root = etree.HTML(htmlSource)
        root = etree.HTML(htmlSource)
        result = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, method="html")

        self.expr1 = check_reg(root)
        self.expr2 = check_practice(root)
        self.D_expr1 = no_ks(root)
        ...
        self.D_expr8 = Start_date(root)

        #-----Reg_practice-----
        self.R_expr1 = Name_of_practise(root) 
        ...
        self.R_expr9 = Kind_of_practice(root)

        #------Serv_practice -----
        self.S_expr1 = TERYT2(root)
        ...
        self.S_expr7 = Phone_no(root)
```

Then you will be able to use this class like :

```
exampleInstance = Example ( "link you want to use" , 4 ) # the second argument is your 'count' value

# Now you can use attributes of your class to get the values you want
print exampleInstance . expr1
print exampleInstance . S_expr7
```